# Sound doesn't work in Call of Juarez Gunslinger, under wine

Tags: wine, call-of-juarez-gunslinger

I have played this game on Windows before but felt like replaying it, except I now use Xubuntu as my main OS. I got the game to run and even the cutscenes (install windows media player 10 with winetricks) but sound just won't work.

Does anyone know of a fix?

Comment: Hello! I'm not sure if we can help you fix you issue, as you are not playing the game using the way you should- you are using an emulator (wine is not an emulator but whatever?).

Comment: Do you have surround sound going on? Turning it off fixes that problem on Windows

Comment: No, I dont; I did see a lot of pages mentioning that, but most said it _crashed_ the game

Comment: Do you play any other games in WINE? Do you have audio issues with those games as well? It could be that WINE is not using the correct audio drivers, or targeting the wrong device.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc Yeah, other games run fine

Comment: Then unfortunately, I can't be that much help to you since I haven't been using Linux that long myself. Although I have experienced WINE audio issues they were due to WINE not interfacing correctly with my audio drivers -- this problem seems to be specific to CoJ. It sounds like you've already performed your due diligence in getting this game to work, so I would ask about this issue on a more specialized forum (Linux gaming or WINE specific). Not to discount this site, but usually I can only get good answers for Linux or WINE gaming issues on sites designed specifically for them.